# p:calendar for only month and year

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces, datepicker, calendar

I want to have two different primefaces calendars on the same page.

One calendar with date and second with only month and year.

I have used below javascript and css for **calendar with only month and year**.
It is working fine but other calendars are also affected and not displaying dates because of below CSS style.
Is there any way to apply style for particular calendar and not to all?

**javascript** :-

```
$(".monthPicker").datepicker({    
        dateFormat: 'M yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        maxDate: $.now() ,

        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {

            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('M yy', new Date(year,month, 1)));
        }
    });
    $( ".monthPicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date() );  
    $(".monthPicker").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
            my: "center top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: $(this)
        });
    });
```

**CSS**:-

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
   display: none;
 }
```

Comment: I don't see any PrimeFaces in this question...

Comment: p:calendar is primefaces calendar... @Kukeltje

Comment: But there is NO p:calendar in your code above. Could as well be you just using the plain jquet calendar (since that is what you do by using `$(".monthPicker").datepicker(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append another marker class to this kind of datepickers, like this:

```js
$(".monthPicker").datepicker({
        beforeShow : function(input, instance){
            instance.dpDiv.addClass("month-picker")
        }
});
```

```css
.month-picker
{
  border: 2px solid pink
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" class="monthPicker" />
```

Now you can select:

```
.ui-datepicker.month-picker
```